# Is there a better way of solving this The Leetcode ThreeSum problem?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, binary-search

Please I am just curious if there is a better way I can achieve the ***Leetcode ThreeSum problem.***

I came up with this piece of code using Binary Search

```
    // Time Complexity: O(nlogn) + O(nlogn) == O(nlogn)
    // Extra Space Complexity: O(1)
    public static List<List<Integer>> threeSumOptimalSolution(int[] nums) {
        int n = nums.length;
        if (n < 3)
            return Collections.emptyList();
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        int left;
        int right;
        int mid;
        int threeSum;
        for (int firstValue = 0; firstValue < n - 2; firstValue++) {
            if (firstValue == 0 || nums[firstValue] != nums[firstValue - 1]) {
                left = firstValue + 1;
                right = n - 1;
                while (left < right) {
                    mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
                    threeSum = nums[firstValue] + nums[left] + nums[right];
                    if (threeSum < 0) {
                        if (nums[mid] + nums[right] + nums[firstValue] < 0)
                            left = mid + 1;
                        else
                            left++;
                    } else if (threeSum > 0) {
                        if (nums[mid] + nums[left] + nums[firstValue] > 0)
                            right = mid - 1;
                        else
                            right--;
                    } else {
                        result.add(List.of(nums[firstValue], nums[left], nums[right]));
                        left++;

                        while (nums[left] == nums[left - 1] && left < right)
                            left++;

                        while (nums[right] == nums[right - 1] && left < right)
                            right--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I would appreciate an extensive review from individual/individuals.

Comment: I think you're better off checking out the [discussion page](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/discuss/?currentPage=1&orderBy=hot&query=) rather than asking for an extensive review of an answer here. I am also pretty sure this is O(n^2 logn) not O(n logn), but someone can correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I strongly disagree with you on the time complexity. When I submitted this code, it runs faster than the two pointer solution which is n^2. I would appreciate if you keenly double check the complexity. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure whether your "binary search" algorithm misses answers or not (actually it looks suspicious), but it is definitely neither binary search nor logN - just sometimes it is lucky enough and skips some ranges, but sometimes not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best time complexity in the ThreeNums problem I know is O(n^2)
And I think you want to use Two Pointers to finish the problem.
In your Answer, the part Of Binary Search is wrong, I don't know what's are you doing.
The correct method is to traverse the list outside and use Two Pointers inside.
E.g

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {
        List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if(nums[i] > 0) break;
            if(i > 0 && nums[i] == nums[i-1]) continue;
            int left = i+1;
            int right = nums.length-1;
            while(left < right) {
                int sum = nums[i] + nums[left] + nums[right];
                if(sum == 0) { 
                    List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
                    temp.add(nums[i]);
                    temp.add(nums[left]);
                    temp.add(nums[right]);
                    res.add(temp);
                    while(right > left && nums[right] == nums[right-1]) right--;
                    while(right > left && nums[left] == nums[left+1]) left++;
                    right--;
                    left++;
                } else if(sum > 0) {
                    right--;
                } else {
                    left++;
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: I came ip with this solution too. I only wanted to know if there's a better solution. Albeit, I'm thankful.

Comment: actually it is possible to narrow search ranges (but complexity will remain O(N^2)): in case of sorted array there are only two possible situations: all there numbers are zeros, or the least is negative (that is already taken into account), another observation is: `most <= -2 * least` (least + middle + most = 0 => 2 * least + most <= 0)